# Property 'login' not found on type java.lang.String

Tags: java, casting

I've tried to get the value of **selectOneMenu** of Primefaces but it gives an error of not found property. My method in *UserBean* class return an **UserDTO** object and login is not **case-sensitive** in **Entity** class but it still catches an error.

**UserBean** class;

```
public List<UserDTO> getIds() {
    Object[] array = userService.getWrapperData().toArray();
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Object temp : array) {
        for (String s : temp.toString().split(",")) {
            if (("id").equals(s.split("=")[0]))
                values.add(s.split("=")[1]);
        }
    }
    String[] loginVals = new String[ values.size() ];
    values.toArray( loginVals );
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<UserDTO> valuesLogin = (List) values;
    return valuesLogin;
}
```

**UserDTO** entity class;

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USERDTO")
public class UserDTO implements Serializable {

    private String login;

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

}
```

**indexDTO.xhtml**

```
<h:body styleClass="login">
        <h:form id="form">
            <p:dataTable var="users" value="#{userBean.users}" paginator="true"
                widgetVar="usersTable" rows="10" sortMode="multiple"
                paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" selectionMode="single" id="userTable"
                lazy="true">
            <p:column headerText="Id" sortBy="#{users.id}"
                filterBy="#{users.id}">
                <f:facet name="filter">
                    <p:selectOneMenu onchange="PF('usersTable').filter()">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="#{null}"
                            noSelectionOption="true" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{userBean.getIds()}" var="userLogin" itemValue="#{userLogin.login}" itemLabel="#{userLogin.login}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{users.id}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

**Error log;**

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'login' not found on type java.lang.String
```

Comment: What does `userBean.getIds()` returns?

Comment: [1,2,3,5], which is what I already want. @Piro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem in a really weird way.

I changed my UserBean method to this;

```
    public List<UserDTO> getIds() {
        return userService.getWrapperData();
    }
```

And I can pull the ids from **indexDTO.xhtml** after that.

Answer (score 1):

You are casting `List<String>` to `List<UserDTO>`:

```
List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
...
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<UserDTO> valuesLogin = (List) values;
return valuesLogin;
```

You need to create `UserDTO` objects from those strings manually:

```
for(String login : values){
  UserDTO dto = new UserDTO();
  dto.setLogin(login);
  valuesLogin.add(dto);
}
```

Additionally if you would add constructor `UserDTO(String login)` you could map `values` to `valuesLogin` easily:

```
valuesLogin = values.stream().map(UserDTO::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
```